# I'm trying to get sound on Dark Souls: Prepare to Die Edition for the PC, however it won't work

Tags: pc, dark-souls, windows

Here is the background. The sound worked perfectly fine about two days ago. I had a few friends over, and decided to plug in my loudspeakers rather than my headphones. I set that up, and then play the game, audio is working fine. After they leave I use my headphones again without any issue.

Today however, using my headphones I tried to play the game but alas had no sound. I restarted my computer, and tried again, still no sound on my headphones. I plug in my loudspeakers, set them as default, and then start the game, and I get sound coming through my speakers. I then close the game, unplug the speakers, and reopen, but there is no sound on my headphones. I also tried to set them as default and restart again.

TL;DR
My Dark Souls was working good on my headphones till I played it w/ speakers, now it will only work on my speakers.

I have generic speakers and Razer Kraken 7.1 Headphones.

Generic speakers use both a 3.5mm and a USB where Razer is solo USB.

I'm on Windows 8.1, playing Dark souls Prepare to Die Edition from Steam.

Comment: Did you try starting your pc with the headphones plugged in? Or did you plug them in after?

Comment: I have restarted my computer with the headphones plugged in, and I still have no sound from Dark Souls.

Comment: And is it the same case for any other games?

Comment: I have only experienced difficulties with this game, everything else has worked just as it has over the entire period of this problem.

Comment: Try opening the volume mixer by clicking on the speakers icon, there could be a specific setting for the game.

Answer (score 1):

After a reinstall, I believe I went into task manager and closed Kraken APO Sys Audio Launcher and that fixed the issue.

Comment: You can mark your question as resolved ;)